# how to update more than 1 properties of jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql-13

how to update the age and the status at once,

I have a jsonb field type, I need to update 2 properties (age and status).
I am able to update only either age and status, using the command below, how to do update both 'age' and 'status' at once?

```
**Update test Set attributes = jsonb_set(attributes, array['age'],to_jsonb(32))**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jsonb_set` function accepts a `jsonb` value as its first argument and returns another `jsonb` value, which is the result of the modification applied.  You can pass the resulting `jsonb` value to another `jsonb_set` call where you would apply the second change.  This would result in nested `jsonb_set` calls, as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) suggested in the comments.  The statement would look something [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f0e6abb53d921e26697d42160099fd27):

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  attributes = jsonb_set(
                 jsonb_set(attributes, array['age'], to_jsonb(32))
               , array['status']
               , to_jsonb('some new status'::text)
               )
;
```